# How can I sort by few columns?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord, ruby-on-rails-3.2

I wrote scope like this

**/models/code.rb**

```
scope :recent, lambda { |n = 10| includes(:user).where('users.deleted_at' => nil).order("users.last_active_at DESC").limit(n) }
```

However, there are the records that have the same **users.last_active_at** sometimes.

So I tried adding **created_at DESC** to it like below.

```
scope :recent, lambda { |n = 10| includes(:user).where('users.deleted_at' => nil).order("users.last_active_at DESC, created_at DESC").limit(n) }
```

But I get  this error. What's wrong with my code? Indeed there is a column called **created_at** in codes table.

```
Error (Mysql2::Error: Unknown column 'created_at' in 'order clause'
```

Comment: If it's `users`'s `created_at` that you want then use `users.created_at DESC` instead of `created_at DESC`. If it's `codes`'s then use `codes.created_at DESC`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since includes decides whether or not the users are joined to the codes table in one SQL query or 2 separate queries are generated (for performance reasons) you should ensure, that you are referring the users table and its created_at column:

```
    scope :recent, lambda { |n = 10| includes(:user).
      where('users.deleted_at' => nil).
      order("users.last_active_at DESC, users.created_at DESC").
      limit(n) }
```

Also think about merging scopes for responsibility reasons as you can read about here:
[Merge your ActiveRecord scopes](http://chris-on-rails.blogspot.de/2014/07/merge-your-activerecord-scopes.html)